# Why does this query search all rows despite being 'guided'

Tags: mysql

I have historic data for odds of horses in various races so I have 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE `horses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
)

CREATE TABLE `odds` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `raceId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `horseId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `raceId` (`raceId`),
  KEY `horseId` (`horseId`),
)

CREATE TABLE `races` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `venueId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `raceDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `raceTime` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `locationId` (`venueId`,`raceDate`,`raceTime`)
)
```

The horses and races tables are a few thousand rows but the odds table is 20m+ rows, indexed on raceId and horseId (multiple rows per raceId, horseId)

I wanted to extract the horses for a given date. I first tried the naeive **query 1**

```
SELECT `h`.* FROM `races` `r` 
    LEFT JOIN `odds` `o`  ON `o`.`raceId` = `r`.`id` 
    LEFT JOIN `horses` `h` ON `h`.`id` = `o`.`horseId`
    WHERE `r`.`raceDate` = '2018-02-10'
    AND `o`.`horseId` IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY `h`.`id`;
```

but it took 2 mins +

Knowing that I only wanted to consider odds from the given date, I did this (**query 2**):

```
SELECT DISTINCT horseId FROM odds 
WHERE raceId IN (SELECT id FROM races WHERE raceDate = '2018-02-10');
```

This runs in a fraction of a second and gives the 69 horseIds that I need. So it seems it should be a simple matter to get the horses using **query 3**...

```
SELECT * FROM horses WHERE horses.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT horseId FROM odds 
WHERE raceId IN (SELECT id FROM races WHERE raceDate = '2018-02-10'));
```

It works but takes the same time as the first query, in fact the "explain" is very similar.

But if I replace the whole of the part in brackets by the actual 69 horseIds like thus (**query 4**):

```
SELECT * FROM horses WHERE horses.id IN (4885,3653,3356,4886,451,941...)
```

It again runs in a fraction of a second.

I have a query that runs fast now but I want to understand why query 3 is slow? If I execute it in chunks from the inside out, as I would intuitively have thought mySql would do, it's fast.

I do understand that the optimizer won't always create a good execution plan.
But why does mySql run it so inefficiently? It seems a perfectly valid query to me and not very different from the very fast **query 5**

```
SELECT h.* FROM horses h 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT horseId 
       FROM odds WHERE raceId IN (
            SELECT id FROM races WHERE raceDate = '2018-02-10')) st 
        ON st.horseId = h.id 
        WHERE horseId IS NOT NULL;
```

I realise a join is probably better than IN - I could accept that if query 4 was also slow but it isn't, it's a fraction of a second. Hoping for an "a-ha" that might help me in future.

Comment: Please post create statements for your tables (`SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTableName`) and the execution plans for the slow queries (`EXPLAIN SELECT ...`).

Comment: You were partly right - I had date in a covering unique index but it needed to be the first column. It still doesn't answer the question asked but I guess it's irrelevant now. All versions work equally well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct h.*
from races r
join odds o on o.raceId = r.id
join horses h on h.id = o.horceId
where r.date = '2018-02-10'
```

It should work well with the given indexes.

Comment: Nope. I know you meant o.horseId but corrected it, takes 2m+, the same as the other 2 slow queries. I already included a query in the question that performs in a fraction of a second, so it wasn't a fast query I was looking for.  It was why is query 3 so slow when it's two fast queries combined (and not as a join that might produce millions of rows)

Comment: Please post the execution plan for this query. You might miss some indexes.

Comment: I took off the downvote because you didn't have enough info. Not upvoting or accepting because you answered a question I wasn't asking :)

Answer (score 0):

My big problem was that raceDate in the covering index needed to be first.

Still couldn't explain why the query 3 was slow given that if I execute the inner part on its own, it's fast and if I feed the output of that manually into the outer query, it's fast.

MySql must in its wisdom rearrange that query in some way and the index is then important.